# Sql automatically update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this view:
CREATE VIEW
AS

```
SELECT
         p.pr_id
        ,p.arenda
        ,p.PlotArea
        ,p.OwnershipTitle
        ,p.Price
        ,p.NotaryCosts
        ,p.AgentFee
        ,p.CtrNO
        ,isnull(p.Price,0)-isnull(a.Price,0) as Diferente
        ,isnull(p.Price,0)+isnull(p.NotaryCosts,0)+isnull(p.AgentFee,0) as TotalCosts

from  nbProcuri p
      left JOIN nbAchizitii a
      ON p.PlotArea = a.PlotArea and p.CtrNo=a.CtrNo
where a.CtrNO is null and a.PlotArea is null
```

I want to correlate those 2 tables with another one called Cadastrial where I have also a column called PlotArea. The column p.arenda should update itself with value 'yes' if p.PlotArea=c.PlotArea otherwise to fill with no.
Is this possible somewhow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE p
SET p.arenda = CASE WHEN p.PlotArea IS NULL THEN 'no' -- For not matched 
                    ELSE 'yes' -- for matched
               END
FROM nbProcuri p
LEFT JOIN Cadastrial c ON p.PlotArea = c.PlotArea
LEFT JOIN nbAchizitii a
      ON p.PlotArea = a.PlotArea and p.CtrNo = a.CtrNo
WHERE a.CtrNO IS NULL 
  AND a.PlotArea IS NULL;
```

Comment: And could I place this update in my view? I've tried but it gives me some errors. Where should I do it?

Comment: @user1820705 You can join this table `cadastrial` with your view instead.

Comment: :And the update it will act automatically like a computed column for example? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @user1820705 It will act dynamically for each row, yes like a computed column.